Sometimes the screen flickers specifically on Ubuntu 24.04
Now I have Ubuntu 24.04. I like this version because it is beautiful. 
But sometimes the screen blinks. 
I have a V130-15IKB Laptop (Lenovo) - Type 81HN. 
Apparently, there are no drivers for my laptop in the new version of Ubuntu. 
In version 22.04 there was no such screen flashing.
There are drivers only for Windows for my laptop on the Lenovo site.
Intel® Core™ i3-6006U × 4 processor
RAM 12 GB
Integrated graphics Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
---
I noticed that when I move the mouse, the blinking stops. And if I don’t move the mouse, it doesn’t stop. But pressing the keyboard keys does not stop the blinking.
---
I couldn't stand the bugs of Ubuntu 24.04 and switched to 22.04 a long time ago. And there were no problems for a long time. 
But lately the same glitches have started. 
When I boot under the old Linux kernel - then there is no such problem. 
I wonder if this flickering is bad for the laptop? 
How to solve this problem? Switch from Gnome to another desktop environment? Switch to another Linux? Boot old Linux kernel by default? Install version 20.04? Please advise me

A driver would not be for the laptop but for the graphics chip set. So look for a driver for Ubuntu 24.04 for that chip set.

There are no drivers on the Intel site.

This looks like more info for the question. It does not belong in a comment. Add it to the question.

David DE, I moved the comment to the question.

I have the same issue. Use the following command, it will fix your issue. It did work for me.
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-intel

This is an old Intel display driver that is NOT being maintained. The newer the computer, the more problems this package will cause. These drivers aren't even needed and I don't know why they are installed by default and not removed altogether!

It didn't help, it still blinks.

And it feels like it even seems to be blinking more often. I also noticed that it seems that when I move the mouse, the blinking stops.

I noticed that when I move the mouse, the blinking stops. And if I don’t move the mouse, it doesn’t stop. But pressing the keyboard keys does not stop the blinking. I'll add these observations to my question.

Works fine for me. Thanks !

Desktops are a goofy game engine-like renderer now, where it is page flipping and spamming out entire desktops over and over like frames of animation. You are seeing it glitch back to the back buffer (previous frame). Moving the mouse causes something to render, and the "blink" changes because it is all racy.

I couldn't stand the bugs of Ubuntu 24.04 and switched to version 22.04 a long time ago. And for a long time there were no problems. But recently, the same glitches have also started. Booted under the old Linux kernel - there is no such problem.
I wonder if this flickering is bad for a laptop?
How to solve this problem? Switch from Gnome to another desktop environment? Switch to another Linux? Make it load the old Linux kernel by default? Please advise me

I know this question is for a hardware install, but for anyone with a similar problem inside virtualbox I tried to remove xserver-xorg-video-intel but it didn't help. Virtualbox Guest Additions did help.

Works like magic!

I too had this issue until today on my Lenovo X1 Carbon. FINALLY found a solution that worked for me at medium.com by Mohammed Essaid MEZERREG. Sharing it here too.
Short version is
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Find
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Append
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"

Save. Then
sudo update-grub

Reboot. Enjoy. I actually did it using Grub Customizer. Use what ever floats your boat.
Link to full article - https://mohessaid.medium.com/how-to-fix-screen-flickering-in-ubuntu-24-04-lts-8546f26ca55d - Go straight to solution #2.

This is the correct solution according to
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951
